# Looking for a Ninja PC Game where hero arrives in hang glider

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, tandy-1000

I'm looking for a game I played in the early 90's on a Tandy computer. Here are the facts I remember by decreasing order of certainty :

- The beginning of the game is the hero arriving in an hang glider
- The game is viewed from the side
- It was played on a Tandy, most likely before year 1990
- The character is some kind of Ninja infiltrating a base, the game is a mix between adventure and action
- The character can throw ninja stars
- The game has very few colors (Red and green come to mind, I doubt there were more than 4 colors, maybe 8)
- There is some interaction with the environment : some objects can be picked up, and some tv screens can be interacted ?

Despite having basically played only this game in my childhood, I was unable to find it back in all the anthologies I could stumble upon online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [Saboteur II](https://youtu.be/EzHaZGF3C5A). It starts with the character riding a glider, has probably CGA graphics (I had only Hercules adapter, but probably used emucga with this), and seems to be released 1987. I remember it being fairly difficult to play, so never got too far in this game. Maybe because of the graphics emulation too.

Comment: There also seems to be a full play through https://youtu.be/6Km5HKBqvBc

Comment: The game also has a surprisingly thorough Wikipedia entry: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saboteur_II:_Avenging_Angel

Comment: It's definitely this, extremely hard indeed, I don't remember going very far

Comment: It's a tough one alright: https://archive.org/details/msdos_Saboteur_II_1987